# What are some good purist rotacaster / omni wheel designs?

Tags: mindstorms, technic, building, design, robotic

In robotics, rotacasters or omni wheels are often very useful.

It's possible to buy LEGO-compatible ones from some third parties, here's one random example:

[image]

Unfortunately, LEGO has yet to make any themselves, which means if you are looking for a purist solution (because of robotics competition rules for example) you are out of luck.

Or are you? It might be tough to make a small one, but surely it's possible to build one.

What are some good rotacaster / omni wheel designs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have copied a design by Isogawa Yoshihito

[image: omni wheel]

I prefer it over the Lambert Varias design as the wheels are positioned more radially

More pictures in this EuroBricks thread:
https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/76297-isogawayoshihitos-lego-technic-omni-wheel-crab/

Answer (score 9):

Here's a design I've been using, [based on this model by Lambert Varias](https://technabob.com/blog/2010/10/19/lego-metal-slug-tank/):

[image]

It's not a perfect circle, but it is relatively small all things considered:

[image]

It's pretty simple, but here's a partial disassembled version to better show what goes into it:

[image]

Parts shown:

- 1x [55013](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55013)
- 2x [4265c](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4265c)
- 2x [57585](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57585)
- 6x [32013](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32013)
- 6x [32556](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32556)
- 12x [42610](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42610)
- 12x [50945](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50945)

Answer (score 5):

Just stumbled across this little gem of a Lego omni wheel!

[image]

Comment: Which is also by Isogawa Yoshihito, besides it being slightly more esthetic, I do not consider it an improvement on his previous design.